# Cannot read message body from an xml file using java

Tags: java, jaxb, lombok, pojo

I am trying to read the xml file. My xml file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<pickingOrderBeginEventMessage xmlns="http://www.xmlns.walmartstores.com/" xmlns:hdr="http://www.xmlns.walmartstores.com/Header/MessageHeader/1.4/" xmlns:flt="http://www.xmlns.walmartstores.com/1.0/">
<hdr:MessageHeader>
    <hdr:SubId>SUB-EIC1</hdr:SubId>
</hdr:MessageHeader>
<MessageBody>
    <RoutingInfo>
        <SourceNode>
            <location>
                <countryCode>US</countryCode>
            </location>
            <cNodeID>ALPHA</cNodeID>
        </SourceNode>
</MessageBody>
```

I have this java program which reads the xml file:

```
public class TestAssertionForPickBegin {

PickingOrderBeginEventMessage pickBegin;

private static String readFromResources(String fileName) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String contentLine = br.readLine();
    while (contentLine != null) {
        sb.append(contentLine);
        contentLine = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();

    return sb.toString();
}

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() throws IOException, JAXBException {


    String path = "file.xml";

    File file = new File(path);
    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(absolutePath);
    String xmlPickBegin = readFromResources(absolutePath);
    System.out.println("starts...");
    System.out.println(xmlPickBegin);
    System.out.println("ends...");
    pickBegin = Xml.xmlToObject(xmlPickBegin, PickingOrderBeginEventMessage.class);
System.out.println(pickBegin);

 }
}
```

My PickingOrderBeginEventMessage POJO class looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.xmlns.walmartstores.com/")
@Data
public class PickingOrderBeginEventMessage implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


Map<String, String> messageHeader = new HashMap<>();

MessageBodyPickBegin messageBodyPickBegin;
}
```

When I am debugging the code, the pickBegin is unable to retrieve the value of the Message body which is coming as null.

My MessageBody POJO class looks like the following:

```
 @Data
 @XmlRootElement(name = "MessageBody")
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)

 public class MessageBodyPickBegin implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   RoutingInfo routingInfo;
}
```

When I am printing pickBegin I am getting ts giving me the output: `PickingOrderBeginEventMessage(messageHeader={}, messageBodyPickBegin=null)` whereas it should be giving this: `(messageHeader={}, messageBody=MessageBody(routingInfo=RoutingInfo(sourceNode=SourceNode(location=Location(countryCode=US), cNodeID=alpha))`

Can someone please help me to point in the right direction?
Thank you.

Comment: @Abra sorry I got you wring, XML is an inbuilt java class I didnt write it.

Comment: I could not find class `Xml`.